# Getting HubContext as null in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr, signalr-hub

I am working with .NET core application using SignalR. My hub class code is:

```
public class LiveDataHub : Hub
{
    public async Task GetUpdatedDataFromServer()
    {
        try
        {
            var dal = new DAL();
            var dashboardVM = dal.GetDashboardViewModels();

            Clients.Caller.SendAsync("UpdatePortalWithUpdatedData", dashboardVM);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

My Startup.cs code is:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<LiveDataHub>("/LiveDataHub");
        });
}
```

I have another class "ModuleLoader", whose code is:

```
public class ModuleLoader
{
    GlobalCache _globalCache = GlobalCache.GetInstance();
    private readonly IHubContext<LiveDataHub> _hubContext;
    public ModuleLoader()
    {

    }

    public ModuleLoader(IHubContext<LiveDataHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    private void OnAdapterGroupDataReceived(DeviceAdapterGroup deviceAdapterGroup)
    {
        var dal = new DAL();
        dal.InsertOrUpdateAllAdapters(deviceAdapterGroup.AdapterGroup);

        if(deviceAdapterGroup != null)
        {
            dal.InsertAllDeviceAdapter(deviceAdapterGroup);
        }

        var allAdapters = dal.GetAllAdaptersConnectedToDevice(deviceAdapterGroup.DeviceId);
        var adaptersToDelete = allAdapters.Except(deviceAdapterGroup.AdapterGroup.Select(x => x.AdapterId)).ToList();
        if (adaptersToDelete != null && adaptersToDelete.Count > 0)
            dal.DeleteAllAdapters(adaptersToDelete);

        var dashboardVM = dal.GetDashboardViewModels();

        _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("UpdatePortalWithUpdatedData", dashboardVM);

    }
}
```

Issue is that when i run this code, i get the exception that _hubContext is null. How can i resolve it. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You should remove the empty constructor, since that makes no sense. It is probably your problem.

Comment: I am calling ModuleLoader constructor somewhere in my application. What argument should i pass to it, i mean what will be the value of the parameter. Just a bit confused here .@Silvermind

Comment: I mean how can i get the value of hubContext

Comment: So how can i set the value @brandonhein ??

Comment: Dependency injection should call that constructor with the proper arguments. Perhaps if you add the module loader to the services and resolve the module loader manually via the service provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also need to add your `ModuleLoader` class into a DI container if you haven't already. You can use the `.net core` default container as shown below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSignalR();
    services.AddScoped<ModuleLoader>();
}
```